# Passing Token with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, curl, alamofire

I have a question: I `m successfully retrieving a token from my API with Alamofire it is a String. What I want to do is: "take the Token (String) and put it in another request to get some JSON data from API"

CURL:
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Token 5f1884848" http://myurl.com

This is what I got to get the token:

```
 let parameters = [
        "username" : usernameLabel.text!,
        "password" : passwordLabel.text!
    ]

    let credentialData = "\(usernameLabel.text):\(passwordLabel.text)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, requestString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in switch response.result {

        case .Success(let JSON):
            print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

            let response = JSON as! NSDictionary

            //example if there is a token
            self.userToken = response.objectForKey("token") as! String?
            print(self.userToken)

            debugPrint(response)

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")



            }

    }
```

I m trying to save the userToken variable somehow:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
var userToken : String?
```

but my userToken var is always nil

Comment: Since you'e assigning the token to self you can just use self.userToken where you need to use it later on.

Comment: This is what I did to try to save the userToken in a var. But the userToken var is not visible outside of my AlamOfire function :/ `class ViewController: UIViewController {
   
    var userToken : String?`

Comment: it should be... if it's not, check that it's not set to nil from other part of your code (e.g. by setting a breakpoint on your var userToken). Also, check that variable is not nil when you get the dictionary in response

Comment: @sbor85 is it possible you're trying to use self.userToken before the alamofire request has completed?

Comment: Maybe helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123503/call-a-function-before-after-each-alamofire-request